# Need to convert nested bean in java to csv using OpenCsv or any other utility

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, opencsv

I have a spring boot application where need to send back application/csv response for list of object having nested beans needs to be converted to CSV using openCsv or any other tool.
e.g. Java classes:

```
class MyData {
    Lis<Person> persons;
}

class Person {
    String id;
    String lname;
    String fname;
    Date dob;
    Address address;
}

class Address {
    String line1;
    String line2;
    String pinCode;
}
```

CSV data:

```
id      lname   fname   line1           line2
1       Doe     John    123 Main St     Anytown, USA
2       Dean    James   111 Some St     Othertown, USA
3       Burger  Sam     99 Beach Avenue Sometown, USA
```

Note that, few fields like Prson.dob & Person.Address.pinCode are excluded from the conversion.
Sample code will help a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933155/opencsv-convert-object-with-nested-bean-to-csv. Did you find any answer for the same?

Comment: @SatyaKinkarGorai I could not find any automated way for this. So, right now, i'm iterating over the java list & converting them in csv row. Please let me know if you find any automated way. thanks.